# Get column value when another column is max in google query when grouping

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Suppose I have a table like so:

| one | ID | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | one |
| b | 7 | two |
| c | 6 | three |
| a | 9 | four |
| b | 3 | five |
| c | 1 | six |
| a | 5 | seven |
| b | 10 | eight |
| c | 8 | nine |
| a | 4 | ten |

I want to `GROUP BY` `one`, get `MAX` of `ID` and then get the associated value from `three`.

I can do the first part like so:

```
=QUERY(A1:C11, "SELECT A, MAX(B) GROUP BY A")
```

To get:

| one | max ID |
| --- | --- |
| a | 9 |
| b | 10 |
| c | 8 |

But I want to get:

| one | max ID | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 9 | four |
| b | 10 | eight |
| c | 8 | nine |

I am trying to do this all with one `QUERY`. I know I could use a `VLOOKUP` for the 3rd column but I'm hoping there is way to do with one `QUERY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation-functions) documentation, it is explicity stated in the rules of the `GROUP BY` clause that **every** column in the `SELECT` must be a grouped column -or- wrapped by an aggregation function. This is why it is not possible to include an ungrouped, unaggregated column in your specific query.

You can do the workaround as per player0's answer, but if you want to use `QUERY()` and`VLOOKUP()` in a single formula you can use this as well:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{QUERY(A1:C,"SELECT A, max(B) where A is not null group by A")},{VLOOKUP(FILTER(F:F,LEN(F:F)),SORT(B1:C,1,TRUE),2)}})
```

Sample:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:C, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
={QUERY(source!A:E, 
 "select B,C,max(A) where D is not null group by B,C", 1), 
 {"value"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(source!A:E, 
 "select B,C,max(A) where D is not null group by B,C", 1), 
 "offset 1", 0),,1)<>"", 
 VLOOKUP(INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(source!A:E, 
 "select B,C,max(A) where D is not null group by B,C", 1), 
 "offset 1", 0),,3), source!A:E, 5, 0), ))}}
```

[image]

Comment: This work but the reason I am trying to use `QUERY` is my source data is from another table with multiple columns that I am pulling in and filtering out: `SELECT G, D, MAX(A) WHERE L IS NOT NULL GROUP BY G, D`.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: It sounds like I can't do what I want with `QUERY` but, since I know you like a challenge, I created a dummy sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6XszerMpGamWbLhhkahruDLFpszQ-7fMML4RNJ6SG4/edit?usp=sharing.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work.  You can & the columns together pre-query, then split them out afterwards.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY({A:A,TEXT(B:B,"000000000")&"|"&C:C&"|"&A:A},"select MAX(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1",1),"|"),"select Col3,Col1,Col2"))
```

[image: formula working]